# Performance problem when using UITextView

Tags: iphone, performance, xcode, uitextview

I am having a performance issue.

I have developed an app, I had no problems
with the navigation, the app was working smoothly. 
Until I added the UITextView, when clicking
the button which switches the view to the view where
I used the TextView, it takes about 4 to 5 seconds to 
switch the view. This happens when filling the textView 
with about 30-40 lines of text.

I added the TextView using the interface builder, whiteout
adding any code related to UITextView in Xcode.

Can you please help me solving this issue ??

Thanks.

EDIT: This is the code for the page containing the TextView

```
//  Food.m
//  Azkar
//
//  Created by al3madi on 18/02/2011.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Food.h"
#import "MainMenuViewController.h"


@implementation Food

- (IBAction) mainMenu:(id)sender {
    MainMenuViewController* mainM = [[MainMenuViewController
                                      alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenuViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainM animated:YES];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [MainMenuViewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

NOTE: I have entered the text in the XIB file using the Interface Builder, not by coding, where I have changed the content of the TextView to the text I wanted. I also made the 
TextView not editable.

The code is in Food.m
The TextView content is in Food.xib

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code where you are populating the UITextView...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, as I said, the code does not contain any thing related to the UITextView.. I do not know how to add codes but I hope you can read it ,,, [code]   #import "Food.h"
#import "MainMenuViewController.h"


@implementation Food

- (IBAction) mainMenu:(id)sender {
 MainMenuViewController* mainM = [[MainMenuViewController
           alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenuViewController" bundle:nil];
 
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainM animated:YES];
}


- (void)dealloc {
 [MainMenuViewController release];
 [super dealloc];
}


@end
[code]

Comment: Edit your question, add the code there, highlight it, and press the `{}` button.  But show the code where you actually fill the textview.

Comment: You cannot dealloc the class. There must be something missing/wrong in the code above. In your dealloc method, you are releasing the class by [MainMenuViewController release];, i guess you can only release the objects
    [super dealloc];
}

Comment: Sorry I was just trying releasing the class, I thought it might work :p .. I removed [MainMenuViewController release]; and released the UITextView, but still the same

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit weird. Anyway, try the following. Instead of putting the text in your `UITextView` using Interface Builder, do this programmatically. In the view controller responsible for handling your `UITextView`, simply add the following line in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
myTextView.text = @"your text here";
```

`myTextView` is the name you assigned to the outlet variable associated to your `UITextView`.

Comment: Hello,  I have just tried it, still the same thing takes about 4 seconds to navigate from the main menu to Food.xib.

Comment: What kind of device are you using? Are you sure you have properly compiled your code enabling optimization? When you run your app in debug configuration there are no optimizations in place, so that the code is much slower w.r.t. a release configuration. But 4 seconds seems to me too much, even in debug configuration.

Comment: When running the app using the simulator it fast and has no problems,, but when I run it on my device "iPhone 4" it becomes much slower.